# How to delete mapped data by fetching its id in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have mapped data which coming from database, while i am giving button to delete that data from the page and database it is not working.
Code is given below.

```
class View extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            dealdata: [],

        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/getdeals')
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({ dealdata:res.data })
            console.log("recived deals : "+ this.state.dealdata);
            this.forceUpdate()
        })

      }
      deleteItem(e){
        console.log("ids"+e.target)
      }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Col xs="12" md="6">
                {this.state.data.map(item => (
            <Card color="light" className="cards">
            <CardBody>
              <label>{item.percentage}% Deal on {item.on}{item._id}</label>
              <Button size="sm" className="btn-facebook btn-brand icon mr-1 mb-1" ><span>EDIT</span></Button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <Button size="sm" className="btn-youtube btn-brand icon mr-1 mb-1" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this,item._id)} >DELETE</Button>

              </CardBody>
            </Card>

       ))}
      </Col>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default View
```

but while running this code id is not passing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

button code changed to :-

```
<Button size="sm" className="btn-youtube btn-brand icon mr-1 mb-1" onClick={this.deleteItem} value={item._id} >DELETE</Button>
```

and event handling changes to :-

```
 deleteItem(e){
        console.log("ids"+e.target.value)
     }
```

Now its working.. Thanks for all to all those who help me...

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the value of `id` in event handler so it will be available as first argument of the event handler function, then the event object.

Write it like this:

```
deleteItem(id, e){
   console.log("ids", id, e.target)
}
```

Check [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for more detail about, how bind works.

Working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = { arr: [1,2,3,4] }
  }
  
  deleteItem(id, e) {
    console.log('id', id, e.target);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.arr.map(el => <div>
             {el}
             <button onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, el)}>
                Delete
             </button>
          </div>)
        }
      </div>
    )
  }  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
```

Comment: facing any issue?

Answer (score 0):

It should have `e` and `id` as attributes as per the order in jsx:

```
deleteItem(e, id){
   console.log("ids", id, e.target)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code.

First one is mentioned in the other answers you need to use both `id` and `event` in your `deleteItem` function.

```
deleteItem(id, e) {
    console.log("ids", id, e.target);
}
```

Second problem is that your are mapping for the wrong state value. You are trying on `this.state.data` but you have `this.state.dealdata`.

Here is the full code:

import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import { Col, Card, CardBody, Button } from "reactstrap";
import axios from "axios";

```
class View extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    dealdata: [],
  };
}

componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/getdeals')
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({ dealdata:res.data })
            console.log("recived deals : "+ this.state.dealdata);
            this.forceUpdate()
        })

      }

deleteItem(id, e) {
  console.log("ids", id, e.target);
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Col xs="12" md="6">
        {this.state.dealdata.map(item => (
          <Card color="light" className="cards">
            <CardBody>
              <label>
                {item.percentage}% Deal on {item.on}
                {item._id}
              </label>
              <Button
                size="sm"
                className="btn-facebook btn-brand icon mr-1 mb-1"
              >
                <span>EDIT</span>
              </Button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <Button
                size="sm"
                className="btn-youtube btn-brand icon mr-1 mb-1"
                onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, item._id)}
              >
                DELETE
              </Button>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </Col>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Also, you don't need `forceUpdate` here, why do you use it? You are already setting your state, so your component will be rerendered. One other point do not use `console.log` to see your state right after setting your state. `setState` is an async operation, you can't get healthy results like that. Either log it in your render method or use the callback with `setState`:

```
this.setState({ dealdata:res.data }, () => console.log(this.state.dealdata) );
```

Lastly, I recommend refactoring an `Item` component for each item. With your current code, you are binding your functions directly in your JSX prop. Those functions are recreated every time this component rendered. For a small app this is not a problem but for a big one performance problems can be seen. Create a new component, map it, pass each item to it, then with a callback function deal your `delete` or other actions. Since you will have the `_id`s you can pass those back and do the other staff in your parent component (View).